# Como comparar 2 potencias

Tags: javascript

Eu preciso comparar 2 potencias que não estão formatadas..

Exemplo:
`2,2 = 2²`
`3,3 = 3³`

`if (2² > 3³)`

os numeros chegam em um array, vem assim [2,2,3,3], eu preciso separar eles em duplas e preciso fazer virar uma potencia...

Comment: Como você pretende representá-las antes da formatação? Dois números num array `[2,2]`, uma string `"2,2"`, outro formato?

Comment: Bom, o mais simples parece ser calculá-las e comparar os resultados: `if ( Math.pow(arr[0], arr[1]) > Math.pow(arr[2], arr[3]) )`. P.S. Alguém poderia comentar a razão dos votos contra?

Comment: Você pode usar a função `Math.pow(base, expoente);`

Comment: Nossa @mgibsonbr, a frase na minha resposta ficou quase idêntica à do seu comentário.

Comment: E, caso as potencias sejam muito grandes, o que pode dar overflow, voce pode comparar os logs.

Comment: Curiosidade: Caso você se interesse pelo aspecto matemático, Como comparar potências: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97022/comparing-numbers-in-form-xy

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) para calcular as potências, e compare os resultados. Por exemplo:

```
var entrada = [2,2,3,3];
// confiando que entrada.length >= 4
if(Math.pow(entrada[0], entrada[1]) > Math.pow(entrada[2], entrada[3])) {
   // a primeira dupla é maior
}
```